# hard question on singularities

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

If every series converging to the singularity has a sub sequence such that limit of the function of the subsequence is zero what can the singularity be?

Comment: How about: since $\lim_n f(z_{n}) = 0$ because it has a convergent sub-series. Combined with $\lim_n z_n = z_0$ this means $$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z) = 0$$ Which classifies as a removable singularity...

Comment: Thanks but giving a formal proof for that is a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\lim_{z\to z_0} |f(z)|$ doe not exists. Then there exists two seqences $v_n , w_n \to z_0 $ such that $|f(v_n )\to a $ and $|f(w_n ) |\to b$ and $a\neq b$. But there also must exists subeqences $v_{r_n} $ and $w_{r_n} $ such that $|f(v_{r_n} )|\to 0$ and $|f(w_{r_n} )|\to 0$ but this is impossible. So the limit  $\lim_{z\to z_0} |f(z)|$ exists and hence $f$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of $z_0.$

Comment: Bounded and by Riemann's theorem has a removable singularity. Brilliant !

Comment: But  if $\lim_{z\to z_0} |f(z)|$ does not exist can't we have the possibility that $\lim|f(v_n )$ does not exist for any sequence?